# react-select-search - Uncaught TypeError: this.state.value.slice is not a function

Tags: frontend, react, npm

I am working on a ReactJS web app and using "**react-select-search**" package for search & select feature for countries' ISD codes.

[GitHub link to package used](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select-search)

I've cross checked the values from `onChange` function from my below code:

```
<SelectSearch 
    options={this.state.optionsCountryCode} 
    id="customer_isd_code" 
    name="customer_isd_code" 
    className="select-search-box" 
    value="" 
    placeholder="ISD" 
    onChange={
        (value, state, props) => {
            console.log(value);
            console.log(state);
            console.log(props);
        }
    }
 />
```

And, the values are assigned properly when dropdown value is changed for the first time.

The next time, I click on any dropdown item, it generates the following error in console:

[image]

By digging further into the error location, I found the error in this line of code (inside the package):

[image]

> Note: Backend is in Magento 2 which does not have any relevance with the issue however.

Please check and guide me on locating a solution for this issue.

Comment: Can you please check the what type of value return for this.state.value: EX console.log(this.state.value)

Comment: Yes, it returns the following result `{name: "Vanuatu (+678)", value: 230, index: 229}`

Comment: Yupp. But, that's the package's default code naa. Is it good to modify it?

Comment: No, please do not modify default files

Comment: The above code 'SelectSearch  options={this.state.optionsCountryCode} ' is this default or custom code?

Comment: `this.state.optionsCountryCode` : I've created this a state array, passed to the `options`. It's prescribed in package. Plz have a look at the Github link shared with the question. The variable do have a list of ISD codes with country names. e.g. `[{name: "Vanuatu (+678)", value: 230}, {name: "Canada (+1)", value: 1}]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102577/discussion-between-medeepakjain-and-birjitsinh-zala).